# Teamcity buildagent system log alerts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, teamcity

We currently have our dev server running Teamcity 7.1 and have been building / publishing without a problem.  Recently though, we noticed that whenever an error is generated in the Application logs, instead of getting the error from the live .pdb (C:\inetpub\wwwroot[SiteName]\bin), its getting it from the build agent work location(c:\BuildAgent\work\92648d34566a49aa[SiteName]).

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NotImplementedException 
    Exception message: Pew ^ Pew
    at MyProject.Controllers.ErrorController.ThrowError() in c:\BuildAgent\work\92648d34566a49aa\MyProject\Controllers\ErrorController.cs:line 38
    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
    at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
```

I checked our build steps and parameters (using MSBUILD) and the only thing that currently points to the build agent is XUnit, but this issue persists even with the XUnit build step disabled.

My thought would be that instead of showing the build agent location, it should show the sites URL or live location.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception occurs in a .NET assembly that has debugging information, the paths in the pdb files will be the paths of the source file where the assembly was compiled. In this case, that is c:\BuildAgent\work\92648d34566a49aa....